# Design app/server architecture, to detect which version to route the request?

Tags: android, versioning

When we have different versions of our app running in the production/testing then do app developers send app version along with the request to the server/OR (store it once at the server) to decide which server version this request belongs to.

If anybody of you has deployed your android/ios app then what kind of architecture you have followed?

What are the **possible ways** to implement this kind of mechanism?

I am using NodeJs Server in the backend and android app on the client side.

Thanks

Comment: This is more of an architectural question than a development one, so I would recommend checking out the [REST Api Versioning Guide](https://restfulapi.net/versioning/)

Comment: @Cruceo Thanks, but actually there was no mentioning of client-side versioning.

Comment: Those are all methods of versioning both the clients and your server. Updated versions of a client can either point to new endpoints (x.y.com/api/v2/endpoint) or supply some kind of versioning information in the request headers (i.e. an Api-Version header).